# Bold the entire row based on a cell's font

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of data in columns A to Z, if any cells in Column F is bolded, shall call to bold the entire row.

For example, F3 and F80 is bolded. A3:Z3 and A80:Z80 shall be bolded. My code only works until bolding cells in column F, can't proceed to bold the entire row.

```
Sub Bold()

    Dim CheckRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    With ActiveSheet
        Set CheckRange = .Range("F2:F" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row)

    End With

    With CheckRange
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreaterEqual, formula1:="1000000"
        With .FormatConditions(1)
             .Font.Bold = True
             .StopIfTrue = False
        End With

    For Each cell In CheckRange
        If cell(cell.Row, 6).Font.Bold = True Then
            cell.EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: still cant get it after 7 posts in 24 hours, eh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be using a formula for the conditional formatting is better

```
Sub Bold()
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .Range("A1:Z" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$F1>=1000000"
    With .FormatConditions(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .StopIfTrue = False
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

Or to adhere to your code you can use offset and resize in the loop

```
Sub Bold()
Dim checkRange As Range, cell As Range

With ActiveSheet
    Set checkRange = .Range("F2:F" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row)
End With

With checkRange
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreaterEqual, Formula1:="1000000"
    With .FormatConditions(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .StopIfTrue = False
    End With
End With

For Each cell In checkRange
    If cell.DisplayFormat.Font.Bold = True Then
        cell.Offset(, -5).Resize(1, 26).Font.Bold = True
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Both methods work just fine! Thanks a bunch! May I know how does Offset and Resize work in this case? `cell.Offset(, -5).Resize(1, 26).Font.Bold = True`

Comment: You're welcome. As cell in column F so offset by -5 will make the cell address is in Column A then from A to Z is 26 Columns so I used Resize.

Answer (score 0):

The code sample is missing an `end with` after the first one to run.

Other than that, the issue is here: `If cell(cell.Row, 6).Font.Bold`

`cell` is already a Range type reference to the cell you need, so you don't need to look up anything, in fact doing that causes it to point elsewhere with the cell function: for example this is from the watch window, note the value difference:

```
Watch :   : cell.Address              : "$F$2" : String         : Module1.Bold
Watch :   : cell(cell.Row, 6).Address : "$K$3" : Variant/String : Module1.Bold
```

This is the full code:

```
Sub Bold()

    Dim CheckRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    With ActiveSheet
        Set CheckRange = .Range("F2:F" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row)

    End With

    With CheckRange
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreaterEqual, Formula1:="1000000"
        With .FormatConditions(1)
             .Font.Bold = True
             .StopIfTrue = False
        End With
    End With

    For Each cell In CheckRange
        If cell.Font.Bold = True Then
            cell.EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```